# How to add pagination during filtered in django

Tags: python, django

my url appear like this '''http://127.0.0.1:8000/menu/?[%27tags%27,%20%271%27]&page=2'''

I want to make 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/menu/?tags=2&page=2'

Thank you all..

munu_extras.py

```
from django import template
from ..models import Menu
register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def my_url(value,field_name,urlencode=None):
    url = "{}={}".format(field_name,value )


    if urlencode:
        querystring = urlencode.split('=')
        filtered_querystring = filter(lambda p: p.split('=')[0]!=field_name, querystring)
        print(filtered_querystring)
        encode_querystring = '='.join(filtered_querystring)
        url = '?{}&{}'.format(querystring,url)

        
    return url
```

In My menu.html

```
        {% if menus.has_previous %}
            <a href="{% my_url 1 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}"><<<</a>
            <a href="{% my_url menus.previous_page_number 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}"><<</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if menus.has_next %}
            <a href="{% my_url menus.next_page_number 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">>></a>
            <a href="{% my_url menus.paginator.num_pages 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">>>></a>
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `request.GET`. So when you enter the url  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/menu/?tags=2&page=2`. The part after the `?` will be resulted in `request.GET`.
Suppose, if your `urls.py`, you have a url:
`path('menu',views.function,name='function')` and in `views.py` you have a function:

```
def function(request):
    print(request.GET)
    return HttpResponse('success')
```

In the print statement output, it will be a dictionary with keys `tags` and `page` with values `2` and `2` respectively

Comment: `myFilter = MenuFilter(request.GET,queryset=menus)
 menus = myFilter.qs` I already used...

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting the url-encoded GET parameters on `=` instead of `&`, and various similar mistakes.

```
@register.simple_tag
def my_url(value, field_name, urlencode=None):
    url = "?{}={}".format(field_name, value)

    if urlencode:
        querystring = urlencode.split('&')
        filtered_querystring = filter(lambda p: p.split('=')[0] != field_name, querystring)
        encoded_querystring = '&'.join(filtered_querystring)
        url = '{}&{}'.format(url, encoded_querystring)
    return url
```